# Parse error with CLI while login to Parse (panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference)

Tags: parse-platform, command-line-interface, parse-cloud-code

Everything was working just fine few days ago. i don't remember what exactly i did to cause the problem.
First of all, when i was trying to list out all the Parse apps for my current codebase with `parse list`, it asked me to login which i did. immediately after i input the credentials, Parse responses me with below error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x591f]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.(*apps).restFetchApps(0x10693400, 0x106aa440, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/apps.go:132 +0x16f
main.(*login).authUser(0x10693340, 0x106aa440, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/login.go:202 +0x1bd
main.(*listCmd).run(0x4e9d1c, 0x106aa440, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/list_cmd.go:33 +0x5e
main.*listCmd.(main.run)·fm(0x106aa440, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/list_cmd.go:47 +0x39
main.func·013(0x1065b180, 0x4e9d1c, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/main.go:168 +0x127
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x1065b180, 0x4e9d1c, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:399 +0x29b
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).findAndExecute(0x1065a960, 0x10676680, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:366 +0x9b
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0x1065a960, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/me/src/go/src/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:452 +0x834
main.main()
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/main.go:415 +0x913

goroutine 5 [syscall]:
os/signal.loop()
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:21 +0x1b
created by os/signal.init·1
    /usr/local/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:27 +0x2e

goroutine 6 [chan receive]:
main.func·019()
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/main.go:347 +0x33
created by main.main
    /home/me/src/go/src/parse.com/cmd/parse-cli/main.go:349 +0x136

goroutine 13 [sleep]:
net.func·019()
    /usr/local/go/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go:240 +0x4e
created by net.loadConfig
    /usr/local/go/src/net/dnsclient_unix.go:269 +0x1a4
```

I also couldn't deploy the my code to parse with `parse deploy`

```
Uploading source files
Deploy failed. Retrying deploy...

Uploading source files
dial tcp: lookup api.parse.com on xxx.xxx.xx.x:xx: cannot unmarshal DNS message
```

I guess something just went wrong with the Parse command line tools, anyone encountered this problem before ?

Comment: I got this error all of the sudden today, too! Not sure what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what caused the error. I was able to resolve this on my mac by turning wifi off, then on again. Hope it helps someone who might still be struggling with it.